# DELETE (all caps) reserved in C/C++?

Tags: c++

I have an enumerated data type in a socket library for PUT, POST, and GET.  I added DELETE, but it came up with errors until I changed it DELETECMD. Is DELETE (in all caps) a reserved word in c++?  If so, for what?  (I'm already well aware of the normal "delete" function)  It's not a problem, I'm just curious.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: What were the errors it came up with?

Comment: what is the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not reserved by C or C++, but it is used in Windows. It's one of the [standard access rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379607.aspx), along with READ_CONTROL, SYNCHRONIZE, WRITE_DAC, and WRITE_OWNER. They're defined in *winnt.h*, which you'll get implicitly whenever you include *windows.h*.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I am using Visual Studio 2005 and have the Windows SDK 7.1 linked in.

Answer (score 6):

`DELETE` is not a reserved keyword, `delete` is (and is not a function but an operator). There might be a macro definition somewhere defining `DELETE`, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE in all caps is not a keyword in C++. This behavior can be caused by a previous variable definition or a preprocessor definition in an included header file:

```
//someheader.h

#define DELETE delete

//yourfile.cpp

#include "someheader.h"

//whatever....
int DELETE;
//......
```